# How do I hide the title bar in full-screen mode in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2?

Tags: intellij-idea

This only happened after updating to IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2 CE.  The title bar (which, in non-fullscreen mode, contains the project name and the root project directory) is still visible in fullscreen.  Is there a way to hide it?  This screenshot was taken in fullscreen mode, and that big empty bar at the top is driving me crazy.

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce in the stock IntelliJ IDEA installation. Please specify your Java version (in Help | About), your OS and if the issue persists without the third-party Material UI theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is caused by the Material UI theme.  Disabling that plugin fixed it.  Boo.

Comment: You can vote for https://github.com/ChrisRM/material-theme-jetbrains/issues/1300.

Answer (score 2):

Just disable this option, restart and the title bar is gone.

[image]

Comment: this should be chosen as answer